Customize loss function for categorical crossentropy loss
I'm building a spelling correction model with tensorflow.keras. Currently I'm having a bit of trouble with building the loss function.
My model gives output as 2 classifiers: One is the detector, which helps identify which words are wrong in a sentence. The second is the correction kit, serving error correction.
According to the research paper I referenced, they mentioned how to build the loss function as follows: loss function
Because I don't know how to filter out words that the model thinks are wrong to calculate a classification loss on, I'm using a correction classifier for the entire output for now.
@tf.function
def training_step(model, optimizer, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        correction_output, detection_output = model(x)
        loss1 = correction_loss(y[0], correction_output)
        loss2 = detection_loss(y[1], detection_output)
        total_loss = loss1 + loss2

    gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

    return total_loss


def correction_loss(true_outputs, pred_outputs):
    softmax_loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)(true_outputs, pred_outputs)
    return softmax_loss


def detection_loss(true_detection_infos, pred_detection_infos):
    sigmoid_loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)(true_detection_infos, pred_detection_infos)
    return sigmoid_loss


This way of doing it doesn't seem to achieve a very good spelling correction effect. I need to build the loss function as the article instructs to achieve the best results, but I really don't know how to customize this categorical function. Are there any tensorflow functions that support this? I provide some more information about the model:
for e in range(config.EPOCHS):
    pbar = tqdm(range(0, len(input_sequences_np), config.BATCH_SIZE))

    for i in pbar:
        input_batch = [
            [input_sequences_np[i:i + config.BATCH_SIZE], input_sentences_lengths_np[i:i + config.BATCH_SIZE]],
            [character_level_input_sequences_np[i:i + config.BATCH_SIZE],
             input_words_lengths_np[i:i + config.BATCH_SIZE]]
        ]
        output_batch = [
            output_sequences_np[i:i + config.BATCH_SIZE],
            correct_infos_np[i:i + config.BATCH_SIZE]
        ]

        total_loss = training_step(model, optimizer, input_batch, output_batch)

        pbar.set_description(f'Epoch {e + 1}/{config.EPOCHS}')
        pbar.set_postfix_str(f'loss: {total_loss:.4f}')
        pbar.refresh()


The output of model has shapes:

correction_output (batch_size, max_sen_len, vocab_size)
detection_output (batch_size, max_sen_len)

